# How to group by One2many field records according to batch number Odoo10?

Tags: filter, group-by, odoo, one2many

I am using Odoo10 and want to group_by/filter One2many field records according to batch number. I tried difference solution but didn't get expected result. So, Anyone can suggest me solution for this problem?

This is same problem like if we want to group by sale order line in sale order according to same product name.

**I'm tried below code:**

```
<field name="weight_cal_machine" mode="tree,form" colspan="4" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list" context="{'group_by':'batch_number'}">
    <tree editable="bottom" delete="false"
          colors="blue:status_type == 'assign'; darkgreen:status_type == 'verify';"
          create="false">
        <field name="batch_number" readonly="1" string="Batch"/>
        <field name="status_type"/>
    </tree>
    <form>
        <group colspan="4" col="4">
            <field name="batch_number" readonly="1"/>
        </group>
    </form>
</field>
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no way to get One2many or Many2many fields grouped like the regular tree views that does not belong to a form field. I have implemented long time ago back into when Odoo was OpenERP 7.0 but required a lot of js widgets customization to get it working. It was a client request. Simply it's not supported by Odoo form widgets out of the box